# PHP stream_socket_client(): unable to connect to https

Tags: php, wordpress, security, ssl, ssl-certificate

I've just noticed the new vulnerability discovered in Wordpress and I'm trying to fix it with the following code (but with any success

```
<?php

$url = 'https://mywebip/wp-login.php?action=lostpassword';
$data = 'user_login=admin&redirect_to=&wp-submit=Get+New+Password';

// use key 'http' even if you send the request to https://...
$options = array(
    'http' => array(
        'header'  => "Host: mailserver\r\nContent-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\nContent-Length: ". strlen($data) ."\r\n",
        'method'  => 'POST',
        'content' => $data,
        'ssl'=>array('verify_peer'=>true, 'capath'=>'/etc/ssl/certs')
    )
);
$context  = stream_context_create($options);
//$result = file_get_contents($url,  false, $context);

$fp = stream_socket_client($url, $errno, $errstr, 30);
//stream_socket_enable_crypto($fp, true, STREAM_CRYPTO_METHOD_SSLv23_CLIENT);

$fp = fopen($url, 'r', false, $context);

if ($fp === FALSE) { /* Handle error */ }

var_dump($result);
?>
```

The error log I got is just like this:

```
PHP Warning:  stream_socket_client(): unable to connect to https://mywebip/wp-login.php?action=lostpassword (Unable to find the socket transport "https" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP?) in /home/jorge/Escritorio/joomla.php on line 18

PHP Warning:  fopen(): Peer certificate CN=`website` did not match expected CN=`mywebip' in /home/jorge/Escritorio/joomla.php on line 21

PHP Warning:  fopen(): Failed to enable crypto in /home/jorge/Escritorio/joomla.php on line 21

PHP Warning:  fopen(https://mywebip/wp-login.php?action=lostpassword): failed to open stream: operation failed in /home/jorge/Escritorio/joomla.php on line 21
```

Where `mywebip` represents the actual ip that hosts my website and `website` and `mailserver` the DNS directions of the services.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Via socket you do not specify a protocol.

http://php.net/stream_socket_client

First parameter:

> **remote_socket**
>
> Address to the socket to connect to.

Adress is only `mywebip`.

You should use CURL instead.

See http://php.net/manual/en/curl.examples.php

The other problem (with `fopen()`, which can handle streams with protocols!) is a malformed/wrong certificate issued by your webserver.

Use this service to debug problems with your webservers certificate:

https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/

Comment: Could you please throw some light on this topic? Because I'm pretty newbie on this. I'm trying to use CURL, but I don't know how to relate with the code I already have. Anyway thanks for your collaboration ;)